# Debug iOS on physical device with third party development certificate and provisioning profile

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I am provided with a development certificate and provisioning profile to debug an iOS app. I am able to run the app on a simulator after installing the certificate in my keychain, but the feature I need to work on cannot be tested on a simulator but a real device. I am failing to install the app on that real device, though its udid is listed to the provisioning profile. I am getting the following error.

> The executable was signed with invalid entitlements. Domain:
>   com.apple.dtdevicekit Code: -402620394 Failure Reason: The
>   entitlements specified in your application’s Code Signing Entitlements
>   file are invalid, not permitted, or do not match those specified in
>   your provisioning profile. (0xE8008016).

On xcode, the Team is shown as

> unknown name

in the Signing & Capabilities section. And i guess that is because i am not associated to the developer account where the certificate is from.

My Question is: Do I necessarily need be associated the that developer account to be able to install the app on the device even though the device is in the provisioning profile ?

Thanks for helping out with this.

Comment: Are you trying to run from source or just ran an ad-hoc build that has been supplied?  For the former you will need to have the public and private key for the signing certificate in your keychain. For the latter you should be able to run the app without any keys; since you mention running on the simulator I presume you are running from code so you will need to be part of the developer team or changing the signing and bundle id to one you have access to

Comment: @Paulw11 Thanks! I am running it from the source code, and the certificate i was given contains a private key, And my guess is because i do not have a public key of the certificate I cannot sign the app, in which case i would expect a more specific error message.

Comment: No, it sounds like you have automatic signing enabled. If that is the case then you need to be logged in to the developer team and be a member.

Comment: I am not doing automatic signin since i do not have access to de developer account, i was sent the provisioning profile and the certificate by email. I then installed the certificate on my mac keychain and loaded the p-profile from my file system into xcode that automatically loads the certificate from my system according to the info in the p-profile.